# Creating a decorator for python rq to queue tasks

Tags: python, rq

I'm trying to create a decorator that will automatically queue certain functions.

```
import functools
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn

q = Queue(connection=conn)

def fire_and_forget(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def queue_function(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            q.enqueue(func, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            print('QUEUING FAILED')
            print(str(exc))
            print(func)
            return None

    return queue_function
```

And then I've got some function lets say,

```
@fire_and_forget
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

However, this does not work because the function that is enqueued is the fire_and_forget function, which enqueues another fire_and_forget function and so on. The workers keep endlessly queueing the task.

What is a way around this? I've been trying to figure it out for hours to no avail :\

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this in the end?

Comment: No I found some other workaround that required me to refactor how I was doing things :(